# Improving forecasting output using tbat's method

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, data-mining, tbats

is tbats method the best model to use for my example ? for a weekly seasonality ? i want the predicted data to be like the initial data but that's not the result obtained so here's my data and the final results and the commands ececuted too
[data](https://1fichier.com/?wanu1lltk5)

this is the final result

[image]

and this is the code used :

```
 data.raw=read.csv(file=file.choose(),header=TRUE,sep=";",row.names=NULL)%>%
  mutate(date.re = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
  complete.dates <- range(data.raw$date.re)
  dates.seq <- seq(complete.dates[1], complete.dates[2], by = "week")
  series <- data.frame(sale.week = week(dates.seq),sale.month =    month(dates.seq), sale.year = year(dates.seq))

  data.post <- data.raw %>%
  mutate(sale.week = week(date.re),sale.month = month(date.re),  sale.year = year(date.re)) %>%
  select(Quantite, sale.week,sale.month, sale.year) %>%
  group_by(sale.week,sale.month, sale.year) %>%
   summarize_all(funs(sum(.))) %>%
  right_join(series) %>%
  replace_na(list(Quantite = 0))

  data2=data.post[,4]
  sensor <- ts(data2,frequency=52)
  fit <- tbats(sensor)
  fc <- forecast(fit)
  plot(fc)
```

Comment: If one considers the data in the frequency domain, there is a low frequency that was captured, and a higher frequency that was not captured properly.